# Magento 2 and REST API with Nginx config not working

Tags: magento2, rest-api

We're using a 3rd party software to get data from our Magento 2.1.9 store.

If I click on "get Listings" in this software, it's supposed to download our products from Magento 2.

In our Nginx server error log I find then:

```
2017/10/26 14:18:09 [error] 4183#4183: *713019 open() "/var/www/html/domain.com/www.domain.com/pub/rest/V1/integration/admin/token" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.71.*.40, server: www.domain.com, request: "POST /rest/V1/integration/admin/token HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.com"
```

And the 3rd party software tells me a 404 HTTP error.

Now the 3rd party company is really bad with customer support but I assume  it's because of our Nginx config. Probably that's the bit of interest:

```
    location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}
```

The whole shop and everything seems to be working fine - just not the integration.
Any idea why?

Comment: Could you clarify if you've got the folder? Does pub/rest/V1/integration/admin/token exist on your server?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't exist.
I think no Magento installation has it - it's parameters for the REST API?